# What is unexpected token j in JSON at position 13?

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

I'm working with Postman, and I want it to post a comment for a succeeded or failed try, to sign into my application.
After I run my `body-parser` package with json, and press send on Postman, it doesn't post my comment and pops the error: "unexpected token j in JSON at position 13".

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const database = {
  users: [
    {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Erez',
      email: 'erezrf@gmai.com',
      password: 'bananas',
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date(),
    },
    {
      id: '124',
      name: 'Sally',
      email: 'Sally@gmai.com',
      password: 'avocado',
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date(),
    },
  ],
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('this is working');
});

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
  if (
    req.body.email === database.users[0].email &&
    req.body.password === database.users[0].password
  ) {
    res.json('success');
  } else {
    res.status(400).json('error logging in');
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('app is running!');
});
```

Comment: Can you add the body that you're sending in the Postman POST request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.